# How to create and use a generic bean for enums in f:selectItems?

Tags: java, jsf, generics, enums, managed-bean

I have generic class with this signature:

```
public abstract class EnumListBean<E extends Enum<E>> {

    public List<E> getEnumList() {
        //implementation details
    }

}
```

Currently I have to define a empty subclass in order to access the enumList property for a concrete generic parameter:

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class ItemRarityBean  extends EnumListBean<Item.Rarity>{
}
```

This makes its possible to access the property e.g:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{itemRarityBean.enumList}" var="rarity"
            itemLabel="#{rarity.readableName}" itemValue="#{rarity}" />
```

Im wondering whether one really have to declare a deriving bean but cant access the generic class as bean directly:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{enumListBean<Item.Rarity>.enumList}" var="rarity"
                itemLabel="#{rarity.readableName}" itemValue="#{rarity}" />
```

Comment: You may find [OmniFaces `<o:importConstants>`](https://showcase-omnifaces.rhcloud.com/showcase/taghandlers/importConstants.xhtml) useful.

Comment: In your specific case, it probably wouldn't be useful even if EL could access the concrete parameterised type. There is no way for `new EnumListBean<Item.Rarity>.getEnumList()` to return anything else than `new EnumListBean<SomethingElse>.getEnumList()` without passing a type token because of type erasure. What you could do is fake an indexed property and have a bean indexable by a `Class` that returns the list of its values, but I'm not sure whether you can use class literals in EL.

Comment: @BalusC Wow, nearly the exact thing i want to achieve. Can a `<o:importConstants>` imported enum even be used as list in conjunction with `<f:selectItems>`?

Comment: @BalsusC: Oh I just saw the first example. You might want to post this as an answere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use generics in EL. EL is a runtime language based on reflection. You know, generics is only available during compiletime, not during runtime.

For your particular purpose, it's likely easier to use [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [`<o:importConstants>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/importConstants).

```html
<o:importConstants type="com.example.Item$Rarity" var="Rarity" />
...
<h:selectOneMenu>
    <f:selectItems value="#{Rarity}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

*(the `var` attribute is not mandatory, but you'd otherwise need to reference it as `#{Item$Rarity}` which is not exactly nicely readable; if your `Rarity` enum were a standalone enum and not an inner enum, then you could just use `type="com.example.Rarity"`)*

It's by design treated as a `Map<String, Rarity>`, not a `List<Rarity>` or so. So if you intend to access the individual items in the `var` attribute of `<f:selectItems>`, so that you can access specific enum methods, then you'd need to explicitly iterate over `Map#values()` (which would require EL 2.2 support).

```html
<h:selectOneMenu>
    <f:selectItems value="#{Rarity.values()}" var="rarity" itemValue="#{rarity}" itemLabel="#{rarity.readableName}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to. Because instantiating abstract classes makes no sense.

Comment: The class is just abstract in the current use case. Im free to change th declaration.