# Composite Component and SelectOneMenu with (ENUM) Converter

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, composite-component

I´m trying to create a simple composite component with a selectOneMenu...
It is really simple:

```
<cc:implementation>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <p:outputLabel for="#{cc.attrs.fieldId}" value="#{cc.attrs.fieldLabel}"/>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="#{cc.attrs.fieldId}" required="#{cc.attrs.required}" converter="#{cc.attrs.converter}" value="#{cc.attrs.targetValue}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msg['label.selecione.item']}" itemValue="" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.listValue}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGrid>          
</cc:implementation>
```

So, the problem is when I´m trying to pass the converter! That is an ENUM converter (extends EnumConverter with @FacesConverter(value = "tipoCampoConverter") annotation)

The error is: javax.el.ELException: *Cannot convert tipoCampoConverter of type class java.lang.String to interface javax.faces.convert.Converter*

**EDIT:

Some extra info:

I tried to declare the attribute with and without the 'type':

```
    <cc:attribute name="converter" required="true" type="javax.faces.convert.Converter"/>
```

Some more info:
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.1.10
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 3.4.2
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces Extensions 0.6.1

:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `converter` attribute expects by default a `Converter` instance when the value is a `ValueExpression`. Something like this `<h:inputText converter="#{bean.converter}">`. This unintuitive behaviour in composites is unfortunately "by design".

Your best bet is to use `<f:converter>` instead.

```
<p:selectOneMenu ...>
    ...
    <f:converter converterId="#{cc.attrs.converter}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you do **not** need a converter for this particular use case at all. JSF has already a builtin enum converter. You only need this converter if you're binding an `UISelectMany` component to a `List<E>` instead of `E[]`.

#### See also:

- [Use enum in h:selectManyCheckbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822058/jsf-2-0-use-enum-in-selectmany-menu)
- [OmniFaces `GenericEnumConverter`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/GenericEnumConverter) - a reusable solution for `UISelectMany` with `List<E>`
- [How to create and use a generic bean for enums in f:selectItems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528998/how-to-create-and-use-a-generic-bean-for-enums-in-fselectitems/11529573#11529573)