# Access static property in JSF

Tags: jsf, el, icefaces

I have a static List of Select Items in one of my backing beans:

```
private static List<SelectItem> countries = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
```

with the following getters and setters:

```
public static List<SelectItem> getCountries()     {
    return countries;
}

public static void setCountries(List<SelectItem> countries) {
    LoadSelectItemsBean.countries = countries;
}
```

I am having trouble with accessing the static List through my XHTML page. The code I have tried is as follows:

```
<ace:simpleSelectOneMenu id="countryField"
   value="#{generalCarrierDataViewBean.carrierBean.countryId}">
   <f:selectItems value="#{loadSelectItemsBean.countries}" />
   <ace:ajax />
</ace:simpleSelectOneMenu>
```

The problem line is:

```
 <f:selectItems value="#{loadSelectItemsBean.countries}" />
```

The exception which results is:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /pages/GeneralCarrierData.xhtml @394,64 value="#{loadSelectItemsBean.states}": Property 'states' not found on type com.oag.reference.util.LoadSelectItemsBean
```

Can anbody advise on how to correctly reference a static property from a backing bean?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Properties are per definition not `static`. So getters and setters can simply not be static, although they can in turn reference a static variable. But the outside world does not see that.

You've 3 options:

1. Remove the `static` modifier from the getter. The whole setter is unnecessary, you can just remove it.

   ```
   public List<SelectItem> getCountries()     {
       return countries;
   }
   ```
2. Create an EL function if you really insist in accessing static "properties" (functions). Detail can be found in this answer: [How to create a custom EL function to invoke a static method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function)
3. Turn the whole `List<SelectItem>` thing into an `enum` and make use of [OmniFaces `<o:importConstants>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/importConstants). Detail can be found in this answer: [How to create and use a generic bean for enums in f:selectItems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528998/how-to-create-and-use-a-generic-bean-for-enums-in-fselectitems/11529573#11529573)

Comment: Thank you, I will probably go down the route of option 1 and change my bean to how I previously had it configured.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a non-static method that returns the static property:

```
// here you have a static String
private static String static_str;

public static String getStatic_str() {
    return static_str;
}

// in jsf page: #{myClass.str}
public String getStr() {
    return static_str;
}
```